# How can I exclude the character choice of the first player when the second player makes a choice?

Tags: java

I'm creating a text-based battle game using Java.

This is one of the methods in the `game.java` class, which allows the game to create two characters with the parameters `username`, `character`, and a fixed value of `HP`.

```
public void startGame() {

        System.out.println("\033[1;33mHello! Welcome to the RPG Battle Game!\033[0m");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int users = 2;
        players = new Player[users];
        this.users = users;

        for (int i = 0; i < users ; i++) {
            int playernum = i + 1;
            System.out.print("Enter the name of User " + playernum + ": ");
            String username = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("@ Character list @");
            System.out.println("1. Charizard (Attacks: 2, Attack Power: 10, Defense Power: 0)");
            System.out.println("2. Blaitoise (Attacks: 2, Attack Power: 8, Defense Power: 1)");
            System.out.println("3. Venusaur (Attacks: 2, Attack Power: 5, Defense Power: 2)");
            System.out.println("4. Pikachu (Attacks: 1, Attack Power: 10, Defense Power: 4)");
            System.out.print("Select your Character (Enter the number of character): ");
            Character character = null;
            int characterNumber = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

            if (characterNumber == 1) {character = Charizard;}
            else if (characterNumber == 2) {character = Blaitoise;}
            else if (characterNumber == 3) {character = Venusaur;}
            else if (characterNumber == 4) {character = Pikachu;}
            else {
                System.out.println("ERROR! ENTER A NUMBER FROM 1 TO 4!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            Player player = new Player(username, character, 40);
            players[i] = player;
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Successfully created User " + player.name + " with character " + character.name + ".");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("You created the users successfully.");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        Level newLevel = new Level(level);
        currentLevel = newLevel;
        newLevel.startLevel();
    }
```

The for loop in the method determines the specs of the two players.

Each player can choose a character by typing a number in the console, which is from 1 to 4, determining the type of character. If the number is not between 1 and 4, then the system will force exit. The system makes Player 1 to choose the specs first, and then Player 2.

However, I'm not sure how to exclude the character choice of Player 1 when Player 2 makes his/her choice. This means it is possible to choose the same character for both players, and I'd like to avoid that. The way I want to change the code is not to show the previously selected character in the list,  (making the text grey will be a good idea) or displaying an error message when the same character is chosen again. (probably both)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Extra simple solution:
Make a Map with pokemon_id-player mapping, and then just search if there is already taken pokemon with given id.

More clean solution:
Create Pokemon class with fields like name, attack, attack power, defence power. On the beginning of the game, create list with all the pokemons you want to have. To player class add field with type Pokemon... later when the user picks up pokemon, just assign pokemon to player object and delete pokemon from the original list of them. Problem solved.

Pseudo code:

```
class Pokemon {
    private String name;
    private int attack;
    private int powerAttack;
    private int defenceAttack;

    [...getters, setters, constructor, EQUALS, HASHCODE]

    public String toString(){
        return printf("{0} (Attacks: {1}, Attack Power: {2}, Defense Power: {3})", name, attack, powerAttack, defenceAttack);
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
class Player {
    [... other fields...]

    private Pokemon pokemon;

    [...getters, setters, constructor etc...]
}
```

Game code:

```
List<Pokemon> availablePokemons = new ArraysList<>(Arrays.asList(new Pokemon("sampleName", 1,2,3)));

show_available_pokemons_on_console();

[...]

player.setPokemon(selectedPokemon);
availablePokemons.remove(selectedPokemon);

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, answering your question:

You need to display in some way that the character is not avaliable. I choose showing just '---' instead of the character's number, but you can change the way you do it:

```
System.out.println(characterSelected(1) ? "---" : "1. Charizard (Attacks: 2, Attack Power: 10, Defense Power: 0)");
System.out.println(characterSelected(2) ? "---" : "2. Blaitoise (Attacks: 2, Attack Power: 8, Defense Power: 1)");
System.out.println(characterSelected(3) ? "---" : "3. Venusaur (Attacks: 2, Attack Power: 5, Defense Power: 2)");
System.out.println(characterSelected(4) ? "---" : "4. Pikachu (Attacks: 1, Attack Power: 10, Defense Power: 4)");
```

For that, you would need the `characterSelected(int id)` method:

```
private boolean characterSelected(int id) {
    return selectedCharacters.contains(id);
}
```

Then again, you would need a list of selectedCharacters to do that:

*(outside, as an object variable)*

```
ArrayList<Integer> selectedCharacters = new ArrayList<>();
```

*(at the end of the for loop)*

```
Player player = new Player(username, character, 40);
players[i] = player;
selectedCharacters.add(characterNumber);
```

**A few extra tips:**

- Instead of blocks of if-else, since you are using `int`s, you can use a switch block.
- You should change it so the character selection menu takes the data of each character from the characters itself.

Comment: So, do I have to replace the four system.out.println lines with the following at the top? And, what should I put in the --- that you put in the sample code?

Comment: It's just a suggestion. I strongly recommend you to read how the solution I posted works, so you can adapt it to your code better

Comment: I understand what you mean, and tried the solution. However, the IDE says that it cannot find symbol of `push(int)` in `selectedCharacters.push(characterNumber)` and cannot find symbol of variable `selectedCharacters` in `return selectedCharacters.contains(id)`. I replaced the four `system.out.println` lines with the ones provided in the answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right: it would be .add() instead of .push() (have been programming on javascript lately and it's .push() there). Also: the selectedCharactrs should be initialized outside the method, as an instance variable

Comment: oh no.. I actually couldn't wait for your comment and just divided the for loop into two chunks of code (since users=2, the for loop should repeat twice) and set an if statement that characterNumberP1 == characterNumberP2.. Still works though..